# iOS JavaScriptCore convert from string to JSValue

Tags: ios, javascriptcore

I'm using JavascriptCore. Value from the JavaScript side are wrapped in [JSValue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore/jsvalue?language=objc). I'm assuming sending data from Swift/Objective-C side to the Javascript side also uses JSValue.

However, I noticed that there are calls like `valueWithDouble:inContext`, but how come there is not one for `NSString`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it's not necessary to use JSValue when passing string back to JavaScript. Just use NSString directly.

Comment: How do you send an NSArray back to JS? Any example?

Comment: It's been a while I don't even have XCode running now and I'm still on Mojave, so I don't have code to pull out right off the bat.